# How to generate rows of PanelGrid dynamically? (JSF, Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, javabeans, panel

I'm trying to create a PanelGrid with 2 columns and loading data in it from a **List** . The Problem is that it does not create new rows. It just put the entire **List** in the first row.

There is no communication with the database. It is just a **List** that I need to display, with a row for each value.

This is how my PanelGrid looks like:

```
        <p:panelGrid style="border:10px;">

                <p:row>
                    <p:column style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">Column1</p:column>
                    <p:column style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">Column2</p:column>
                </p:row>

                <p:row>
                    <p:column style="width:35%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myService.columnOne}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column style="width:35%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myService.columnTwo}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

            </p:panelGrid>
```

and this is my List in MyService.java:

```
 public List<String> columnOne = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> columnTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and I simply add some values in my methods with

```
columnOne.add("String");
```

...

**EDIT**

I have solved it by changing my Java Logic, by creating a Key,Value Map and displayed it in a datatable.

Answer (score 2):

In the way you are writing it, of course it won't make but only two rows, one for headers and another containing two cols, they will output the `columnOne.toString()` and `columnTwo.toString()`.

There must be some way to display them in one only `p:panelGrid`. However, if you are sure both lists are of the same size, I think best way (optimized and no extra code is required in your Java code) is to use two `p:panelGrid`s, each of them will display one column. After that, you play with your CSS to make them appear as a unique table.

Based on your comment, here what I should do in my approach:

```
<p:dataTable var="colValue" value="#{myService.columnOne}">    
  <p:column headerText="Column1">  
        <h:outputText value="#{colValue}" />  
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Column two is like column one.

I didn't use `p:panelGrid` to avoid using `c:forEach` when iterating data

Comment: so where do I set the value for the columns? Like I did in my code?
                  <h:outputText value="#{myService.columnOne}" />
Will it create a row for each value?

Comment: if you are willing to use my approach, then I would use p:datatable, see my answer edited

Comment: yor solution works for me, but isn't it possible to set the two columns in one Datatable? Will I really have to create two datatables for each column?

Comment: If you want to preserve your Java logic (each column content in a separated list) then, this is the best way, of course there must be other ways to do it with one only datatable. If you are willing to change your Java logic, then, you can put the columns content in one only list (of objects containing two attributes: columnOne and columnTwo). then iterate on list and access each attribute in a column

Comment: OP want a fixed 2-column table. This answer doesn't provide that.

Comment: @BalusC, This is what I already told him: "There must be some way to display them in one only p:panelGrid" and I edited my answer based on his comment

Comment: @BalusC, please notice in your answer, that OP has two lists, and he wants every column to take values from a list apart. That's why I suggested using two datatables

Comment: Oh right, OP has 2 separate lists for some reason. Nevermind then.

Comment: I have solved it by changing my Java Logic, by creating a Key,Value Map and displayed it in a datatable.

Anyway, thanks BalusC and Laabidi for help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't iterate your list with p:panelGrid
You should use an iterator like p:datatable or p:datagrid

And #{myService.columnOne} will output the object columnOne, not the values inside it.

In datagrid you define a var to iterate the list.

You should define something like this;

```
<p:dataGrid style="border:10px;" value="#{myService.columnOne}" var="col"  columns="3">
    <p:panel header="col" style="text-align:center">
    <h:outputText value="#{col}"/>
  </p:panel>             
 </p:dataGrid>
```

and in bean

```
    public myservice() {
        columnOne.add("String1");
        columnOne.add("String2");
        columnOne.add("String3");

        columnTwo.add("Something1");
        columnTwo.add("Something2");
        columnTwo.add("Something3");

    }
public List<String> getColumnOne() {
    return columnOne;
}
```

Comment: This generates a column for each value

Comment: It's just an example. clearly the questioner doesn't (didn't) understand how to work with iterating a list in JSF. So I tried to explain that part.